# Vim: ci( like ci"?

Tags: vim

In vim, how can I make <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>(</kbd> change whatever is in brackets on the current line like <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>"</kbd> changes everything that is in quotes?

I tried

```
:nnoremap ci( f(lct)
```

but my mapping is ignored. Can I not extend the builtin commands like that?

Also is there any way to combine movements? Can I do something like <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>{</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>)</kbd><kbd>h</kbd><kbd>h</kbd><kbd>}</kbd> to change everything up to the two characters before the closing bracket?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That mapping works for me. However, `ci(` no longer works inside a parenthesized region; is that what you mean?

Comment: Maybe it's some plugin breaking it for me then. How could I make a commandmode command for this? I know I can do 'command what with' to make shortcuts to existing commands, e.g. 'command! CDC :cd %:p:h ', but how can I make commandmode commands emulate keystrokes in normal mode?

Comment: I really cannot get this mapping to work, even when disabling all plugins. What can I do?

Comment: This isn't exactly an answer to your question, but check out [vim-surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround).  Great plugin for this sort of thing.

Comment: Yes, already got that one. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

The behaviors of `ci(` and `ci"` are diferent because vim doesn't consider that quotes (and single quotes) come necessarily in pairs while `({[<` do. This is a bit weird at first.

There are a number of "fixes" to this "issue". [This one is the first that comes to mind.](https://gist.github.com/1171559)